# How to store some data on a click event in JS?

Tags: javascript, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am making an Analytics app in js. I need to get the text from an element that is clicked.
I am using this function to get the data at present.

```
clickfunc = function(link) {
var t = link.innerText || link.textContent;
console.log(t);
}
```

I call this function on a link as-

```
<a href="#work" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>
```

The problem is that, I need to get the data from the element without calling the function in the code, just like in GTM.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"The problem is that, I need to get the data from the element without calling the function in the code, just like in GTM."* I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. Can you describe a bit more? Do you mean you need to get the data without a click?

Comment: Here as I have called the function in `<a href="#work" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>`, I need to make a function that does not have to be called like this.

Comment: But still in response to a click?

Comment: Yes, in response to a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here as I have called the function in `<a href="#work" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>`, I need to make a function that does not have to be called like this.

It sounds like you're asking how to use modern event handling, which is a good idea.

You do it by:

1. Removing the `onclick` from that tag, and either:

   1. Adding script that runs after that element has been created and hooks up a handler for it; or
   2. Adding script that hooks `click` on an ancestor element and then checks, when the click bubbles to that ancestor, whether it passed through that element. (This is called *event delegation*.)

Here's an example of #1:

```html
<a href="#work">this is the #work element</a>
<a href="#life">this is something else</a>
<script>
document.querySelector("a[href='#work']").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.textContent || this.innerText);
});
</script>
```

Note that that code must be evaluated *after* the element exists. There are several ways to do that on modern browsers:

1. Put it in a `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. This works on modern and older and obsolete browsers.
2. Or put the `defer` attribute on the `script` tag (this assumes you're using an external script with a `src`; it doesn't work on inline script). Works on modern browsers.
3. Or wrap the code in a handler for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Works on modern and older browsers.

Here's an example of #2 (event delegation):

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var a = e.target.closest("a[href='#work']");
    if (a) {
        // The event passed through the element on its way to the document
        console.log(a.textContent || a.innerText);
    }
});
</script>
<a href="#work">this is the #work element</a>
<a href="#life">this is something else</a>
```

That `closest` method exists on modern and slightly older browsers but not IE11. If you need to use IE11-compatible code:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var a = e.target;
    while (a && a.nodeType === 1) {
        if (a.tagName === "A" && a.getAttribute("href") === "#work") {
            // The event passed through the element on its way to the document
            console.log(a.textContent || a.innerText);
            break;
        }
        a = a.parentNode;
    }
});
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> Can I do it like `var a = e.target.closest("a[href]")` to reference all the tags having href?

Yes, that's it exactly. `e.target.closest("a[href]")` will match the first `a` element that has an `href` attribute starting from `e.target` and moving up through its ancestors. `e.target.closest("a[href^='#']")` will do that only for `a` elements whose `href` starts with `#`. For instance, here's the example above with two `href="#xyz"` elements that log their text and a the third `href="http://example.com"` that doesn't because it doesn't match:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var a = e.target.closest("a[href^='#']");
    if (a) {
        // The event passed through the element on its way to the document
        console.log(a.textContent || a.innerText);
    }
});
</script>
<div><a href="#work">this is the #work element</a></div>
<div><a href="#life">this is the #life element</a></div>
<div><a href="http://example.com">this is the http://example.com element</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder, in the examples you have provided only one specific tag is being referenced. Can I do it like ` var a = e.target.closest("a[href]")` to reference all the tags having href?

Comment: @Anonymous - Yes, exactly, that will find any `a` element with an `href` attribute (regardless of content). You might then check the result of `a.getAttribute("href")` to see what you want to do. (That gives you the raw value of the attribute, not the resolved URL that you'd get from `a.href`.) That kind of thing is a common use case for event delegation (#2).

Comment: @Anonymous - I've added a live example of doing that.

Comment: how can I get the 'alt' text from an image on being clicked?

Comment: Much the same way, then access the `alt` property (or use `getAttribute("alt")`, but unlike `href`, they're the same thing). More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code into the script tag and put it into the head tag. So, once the dom is loaded it will attach a click listener to all a tag having href.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(function (elms) {
                elms.addEventListener('click', function (link) {
                    var t = link.innerText || link.textContent;
                    console.log(t);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#work">
  <a href="#abc">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you need something like global watcher?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', watchAnchorClicks);

function watchAnchorClicks(event){
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A'){
    var anchor = event.target;
    console.log('Click on anchor with text ' + anchor.innerText + ' and href ' + anchor.href);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph with <a href="#anchor">anchor</a> in.</p>
<p>Yet another paragraph with other <a href="#another">other anchor</a> in.</p>
```